Dynamic displayed message based on shipping zone and cart amount threshold in WooCommerce
On Display a custom message based on customer shipping zone in Woocommerce answer, I found a solution to show a message in cart based on the shipping zone.
I want to show a message based on shipping zones and only if the cart amount is smaller than a specific amount, like:

Shipping Zone 1 and Cart amount is smaller than €29: it should show Text 1
and
Shipping Zone 2 and Cart amount is smaller than €49: it should show Text 2

This is what I tried to edit the PHP code by myself:
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'shipping_notice_displayed', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'shipping_notice_displayed', 20 );
function shipping_notice_displayed() {
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' ) >= 2 ||
        did_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ) >= 2 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Chosen Shipping Method
    $chosen_shipping_zone_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
    $chosen_shipping_zone    = explode(':', $chosen_shipping_method_id)[0];
    $cart_subtotal             = WC()->cart->subtotal; 

    // Settings
    $cart_maximum1             = 29;
    $cart_maximum2             = 49;

    // HERE define the cart maximum 
    if ( $cart_subtotal < $cart_maximum2 && $chosen_shipping_zone != 'Shipping Zone I' ) {
        $cart_maximum = $cart_maximum1;
    } elseif ( $cart_subtotal < $cart_maximum2 && $chosen_shipping_method == 'Shipping Zone I' ) {
        $cart_maximum = $cart_maximum2;
    }

    // Display a message
    if( isset($cart_maximum) ){
        // The message
        $message =  sprintf( 'Above 29,00 € cart total save 5 €!' ,
            is_cart() ? 'Maximum' : 'Max',
            strip_tags( wc_price( $cart_maximum, array('decimals' => 2 ) ) )
        );

        // Display
        echo '</tr><tr class="shipping info"><th>&nbsp;</th><td data-title="Delivery info">'.$message.'</td>';
    }
}

But get some errors and my code doesn't work. How I can display different Cart Messages based on shipping zones and a max cart subtotal?

There are some mistakes and missing things in your code, try the following instead, to display a dynamic Cart Message based on the shipping zone and a threshold cart amount:
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' , 'shipping_zone_message_based_on_cart_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' , 'shipping_zone_message_based_on_cart_amount' );
function shipping_zone_message_based_on_cart_amount() {
    // HERE in the array, define the shipping zone name with threshold max amount (pairs)
    $zone_name_threshold = array(
        'Shipping Zone 1' => 29,
        'Shipping Zone 2' => 49,
    );

    // Get the customer shipping zone name
    $chosen_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); // The chosen shipping mehod
    $instance_id   = end( explode(':', reset($chosen_method) ) );
    $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $instance_id  );
    $zone_name     = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();


    if( isset($zone_name_threshold[$zone_name]) && WC()->cart->subtotal < $zone_name_threshold[$zone_name]){
        echo '</tr>
        <tr class="shipping-info">
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <td data-title="Delivery info">' . sprintf(
                __( "Above %s cart amount, save 5 €!", "woocommerce"), wc_price($zone_name_threshold[$zone_name])
            ) . '</td>';
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.


Hello @LoicTheAztec,
thank you so much for your help!
I added your code to my site, and with Zone 1 it works very well. In my code Zone 1 has to shipping zones called 'Rheinbach Lieferzone I' and  'Rheinbach Lieferzone II'
But where I have to add the different sentence for Zone 2? It should echo for Zone 2 "Ab 49,00 € Warenkorbwert entfällt der Mindermengenzuschlag von 10,00€"

I added your code to my page an changed the Names of Zone 1 and 2 to my Zone names. As you can see with "...Rheinbach..." and "...Irrel...".
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping' , 'shipping_zone_message_based_on_cart_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' , 'shipping_zone_message_based_on_cart_amount' );
function shipping_zone_message_based_on_cart_amount() {

    // HERE in the array, define the shipping zone name with threshold max amount (pairs)

    $zone_name_threshold = array(
        'Rheinbach Lieferzone I' => 29,
        'Rheinbach Lieferzone II' => 29,
        'Irrel 20km Zone' => 49,
    'Irrel bis 30km Zone' => 49,
    'Irrel bis 40km Zone' => 49,
    'Irrel bis 60km Zone' => 49,
    'Irrel bis 80km Zone' => 49,
    );

    $chosen_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); // The chosen shipping mehod
    $instance_id   = end( explode(':', reset($chosen_method) ) );
    $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $instance_id  );
    $zone_name     = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();


    if( isset($zone_name_threshold[$zone_name]) && WC()->cart->subtotal < $zone_name_threshold[$zone_name]){
        echo '</tr>
        <tr class="shipping-info">
            <td data-title="Delivery info" class="deliveryinfo">' . sprintf(
                __( "Ab 29,00 € Warenkorbwert entfällt der Mindermengenzuschlag von 5,00 €!", "woocommerce"), wc_price($zone_name_threshold[$zone_name])
            ) . '</td>';
    }
}

